# Why is tail command not giving a desired result?

Tags: linux

On using

`nl /etc/snort/etc/snort.conf | grep output`

i get the result,

```
33  #  6) Configure output plugins
431 # Step #6: Configure output plugins
```

I need to get the 5 lines before the text `Step #6: Configure output plugins`

So i did

```
tail -n+425 /etc/snort/etc/snort.conf | head -n 6
```

and the result i get is

```
preprocessor ssh: server_ports { 22 } \
autodetect \
max_client_bytes 19600 \
```

Which is wrong!!!.

These lines start from `353`

i want lines to start from `425`

Please Help

Comment: Read documentation of [tail(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) and of [sed(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sed.1.html) and of [nl(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nl.1.html). They are open source programs, and you are allowed to improve them (see [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html)...)

Comment: `-n, --lines=[+]NUM output the last NUM lines, instead of the last 10; or use -n+NUM to output starting with line NUM` . Sir its written there, i am doing it correct

Comment: If you are coding correctly, you don't need any help. And you could write a C program doing what you want, thru appropriate [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (or using  [getline(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) and [stdio(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html)...). Read also documentation of [grep(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) and [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

Comment: I want the lines to start from 425, so tail -n+425 , should start from 425, right? Why is it starting from 353?

Comment: [`seq 100 | tail -n+50 | head -n 5`](https://ideone.com/PSH0j5) works as expected (50..54 lines are displayed)

Comment: did the file `snort.conf` change by any chance between the first and the second commands in your question? Try to reproduce the issue on a separate test file e.g., `seq 100 > test.file`

Comment: There are blank lines there in `snort.conf`. Maybe, thats why i cant get the right number

Comment: no @jfs, conf file isnt changed

Comment: Starting from line 425 is not the same as the last 425 lines.

Comment: @kaylum how can i get the exact number, i used `nl` it gave `431`

Comment: Try `head -n431 /etc/snort/etc/snort.conf | tail -n6`. That gives you the first 431 lines and then gets the last 6 lines of that which is lines 425-431 or the original file.

Comment: Actually, if you know the file is 431 lines then you don't even need the `head`. Just `tail -n6` should do it.

Comment: Tried `head -n431 /etc/snort/etc/snort.conf | tail -n6` , it showed the same result as `tail -n+425 /etc/snort/etc/snort.conf | head -n 6` that is  `353-358`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nl defaults to not counting empty lines, use "nl -ba" to count empty lines.

Comment: Thats it, Thank you, it wasnt counting empty lines, and hence the wrong number